# preciso arrumar meu if

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou fazendo um site de busca no banco e tenho o seguinte código

```
<?php
include("conexao.php");

$pesquisar = $_POST['pesquisar'];
$result_produtos = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE nome LIKE '%$pesquisar%' LIMIT 5";
$resultados_produtos = mysqli_query($conexao, $result_produtos);


if($pesquisar == ""){
    echo "1"
;}else if($pesquisar != $result_produtos){
    echo "2"
;}else{
    while($rows_produtos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados_produtos)){
        echo "O produto: ".$rows_produtos['nome']."<br>"
        ;}
    ;}
?>
```

o `$pesquisa` vem de um `input` no formulário

- quando estiver vazio tem que aparecer `1`
- se estiver errado aparece `2`
- se estiver no banco aparece o **item**

No banco só tem o campo `arroz`, porem quando eu escrevo `arroz` ele está aparecendo `2`

Answer (score -2):

ao invez de usar um `=` no if statment, tente usar um `.contains` ou `.equals`